# When an employer asks about a non-compete agreement, do they mean a non-compete that would interfere with hiring me?

Tags: hiring-process, contracts

I am applying for positions with a company in an industry that does not compete with my current employer (current is a software company for pipelines, prospective is health care). The question 
"*Have you signed and are currently subject to an existing or prior non-compete agreement?*"
 is part of every application for every position I have seen with this employer.

There are other major competitors for the prospective employer in the area and I'm wondering if they mean a non-compete that would interfere with hiring me, or any non-compete at all. To this point I have taken the full honesty approach and said "Yes".

Should I call their HR department directly and ask for clarification?

Comment: Brian, I edited out your code backticks and replaced them with italics. [This Meta](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3941/do-code-backticks-really-have-a-use-on-this-site) gives an explanation of why we don't use them here at The Workplace.

Comment: Note: non-compete agreements are a complex legal issue which may, or may not, be valid or significantly limited in any particular jurisdiction. If it's something that affects you, you should seek competent legal advice.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Calling HR probably wouldn't hurt, but the honest route is always the way to go.

> Yes I signed a non-compete clause with American Widgets not to work for any Widget manufacturer for a period of three years.  However, I want to make clear the fact that this in no way interferes in my eligibility to work for your company, Consolidated Thingamabobs, as you are not considered a competitor and the non-compete does not apply to your company.

Answer (score 13):

Yes - you should call their HR, nobody here knows how they want this answered. But it could be a possible deal breaker if they don't think your position is worth negotiating you out of a non-compete. So they have to be informed that it does not apply here.

If the only possible answer was a Yes/No, I would have ticked no, because I would have assumed they are only interested in applicable non-compete. 
Else I would have written: *yes, but in another industry so it will not apply*.

In the end, you are the one liable for eventually breaching your non-compete, not your new employer. So be sure to get it right

Comment: This is how I was leaning. I have no desire to answer no to the question on the application and have it come back to haunt me later in the hiring process.

Comment: They only care if it affects them, but they want to be the ones to determine that.